# Black screen when I first boot to Ubuntu with USB

Tags: boot

I am using windows 10 and I want to dual boot Ubuntu. I used a USB to boot for the first time with secure boot as 'off'. When I boot, all it shows is a black screen (there is nothing else there). Please help me. I have a geforce gtx 1050. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu: How did you make your bootable USB? What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I think it is a problem with the graphics card. Try with the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset`. Later on, after you have installed Ubuntu, you can install a proprietary nvidia driver [into the installed Ubuntu system] to make the graphics card perform according to its full capability.

Comment: @sudodus: How should the OP boot `nomodeset` if he is booting a ISO9660 disk and is not getting a boot menu? I have been getting a black screen, (with blinking white cursor) while testing Rufus with Groovy, (using ISO image not dd mode).

Comment: It seems I have misunderstood. If there is not even any syslinux or grub menu, the advice of my previous comment will not help. Then you should follow the route suggested by C.S.Cameron.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron: Ubuntu 20.04. I used Rufus to make the USB bootable, my laptop uses UEFI BIOS.

Comment: if you are using Rufus with "ISO image" you should be able to use Sudodus suggestion when booting UEFI and edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` adding `nomodeset` to the end of the line that starts with `linux`. Is it black screen with blinking cursor by the way?